# 'TMapView' does not contain a member named 'Location'

Tags: android, google-maps, delphi, firemonkey

I'm still puzzled as to why I'm getting 'TMapView' does not contain a member named 'Location' at line 47. I did also try to mix and match with the demo code samples but I don't understand what's wrong. My guess is that I would need a private or public declaration..but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to find proper documentation about it...not getting it basically. Please do note that I'm totally new to Delphi programming.

Here's the code:

```
unit MainUnit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.MultiView, FMX.Layouts, FMX.ExtCtrls, FMX.Maps,
  FMX.TabControl;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    MultiView1: TMultiView;
    MainPanel: TPanel;
    HeaderPanel: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    TabControl1: TTabControl;
    TabItem1: TTabItem;
    TabItem2: TTabItem;
    TabControl2: TTabControl;
    PrimaryImageViewer: TImageViewer;
    TabItem3: TTabItem;
    TabItem4: TTabItem;
    PrimaryMapView: TMapView;
    SecondaryMapView: TMapView;
    SecondaryImageViewer: TImageViewer;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure MainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);

begin

  SecondaryMapView.Location := TMapCoordinate.Create(59.965, 30.35);
  SecondaryMapView.Zoom := 10;


end;

end.
```

Comment: Do you understand what the error message means

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do understand what it means, but I don't get how to solve it.

Comment: Do you have the documentation to hand. Does that help.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

[Mobile Tutorial: Using a Map Component to Work with Maps (iOS and Android)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_a_Map_Component_to_Work_with_Maps_(iOS_and_Android))

You need to add a `TMapCoordinate` variable, remove `Location` from line 47 so it can pass the values first, and then you pass the location to the map. Under line 47, add `Location := mapCenter` like below, or see the link above.

```
procedure MainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  mapCenter: TMapCoordinate;
begin
  mapCenter := TMapCoordinate.Create(59.965, 30.35);//this might be a Float
  SecondaryMapView.Location := mapCenter;
  SecondaryMapView.Zoom := 10;
end;
```

Comment: I think this was what I need. I didn't know whag to type to add the TMapCoordinate variable.

Comment: This was the answer, just one more question though...the map still doesn't automatically load on the current user's location, but the specified coordinates instead. How do I go about detecting the current user's location and centering the map based on the user's location by default / automatically?